# Отсутствует шаблон React with ASP.NET Core

Tags: visual-studio

Хотел создать новый проект в котором мне нужен шаблон **React with ASP.NET Core**, но в новой студии 2022 версии 17.9.2 его нет. Где его можно найти?

---

Пример шаблона который был и который нужен (только с TS)

[image: React with ASP.NET Core]

---

Сейчас в списке есть только такие

[image: 5]

P.S. React and ASP.NET Core не подходят так как фронт и бэк на разных портах.